# Crear objeto javascript

Tags: javascript, poo

Es posible inicializar un objeto de manera tal que uno de sus atributos tome el valor de otro?
Esto es lo que estoy intentando hacer:

```javascript
const objeto = {
   atributo1: 1,
   atributo2: objeto.atributo1
};
```

Comment: Tal como lo tienes planteado, no, porque objeto no se ha terminado de declarar... Talvez lo que buscas es hacer un tipo join de objetos, de esa forma, generas dos objetos donde el segundo objeto sii puede acceder a las propiedades del primero, para luego juntarlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Es posible inicializar un objeto de manera tal que uno de sus atributos tome el valor de otro?

Si ejecutamos el ejemplo que colocaste en la pregunta obtendremos el siguiente error:

`"Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'objeto' before initialization"`

```js
const objeto = {
   atributo1: 1,
   atributo2: objeto.atributo1
};
```

Esto significa que cuando intentas asignar `objeto.atributo1` a la propiedad `atributo2` la variable `objeto` todavía no está inicializada aún.

Lo que podrías hacer es lo siguiente:

```js
const objeto = {
   atributo1: 1
};

objeto.atributo2 = objeto.atributo1;

console.log(objeto);
```

Crear la variable `objeto` y abajo inicializar la propiedad `atributo2`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir un [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get); El "problema" (que puede ser el comportamiento deseado según el caso) es que si cambias el valor de `a`, también lo hará el de `b`:

```js
const object = {
  a: 1,
  get b() {
    return this.a
  }
}

object.a = 2

console.log(object.b)
```