# Como guardar en una propiedad de un objeto otra propiedad

Tags: javascript, poo, aplicación-web, objeto

No se ni como empezar a preguntar pero mi problema es este:

- Tengo un Objeto
- A ese objeto necesito agregarle propiedades
- cada una de las propiedades necesita de la otra para hacer conversiones de segundos a minutos de minutos a horas etc  y necesito su resultados

**Mi problema**

Cuando intento guardar un valor de una de mis propiedades a otra propiedad de mi mismo objeto  no lo consigo
ni con ***this*** ni llamando al mismo objeto con la propiedad simplemente da error

*intento hacer algo como esto:*

```javascript
    objeto = {
    propiedad: valor,
    propiedad2: propiedad / Un-numero 
}
// Intenté *this.propiedad* tambien *objeto.propiedad* y  con el nombre de la  *propiedad* y nada funciono para guardar ese valor,
```

también intente guardarlo desde afuera del objeto y si funciono pero quería saber si hay una forma de hacerlo desde adentro del objeto tambien lo hice con una *function(){return this.propiedad}* y funciono pero **mi inquietud es si hay una forma desde adentro del mismo objeto**

Comment: Hoy mismo nos han preguntado casi lo mismo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/507346/crear-objeto-javascript  (mírate la respuesta alli a ver si te sirve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un objeto igual puede tener métodos, en tu caso la propiedad debe ser un método y no un valor estático. Hay un par de formas de conseguir lo que deseas como el uso de [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), pero realmente lo más sencillo es devolver una función en la propiedad.

```js
var cuenta = {
    haberes: 10000, 
    credito: 5000,
    total: function() {
      return this.haberes - this.credito
    }
}

console.log("El balance en la cuenta es:", cuenta.total())
```

La única diferencia es que tu objeto deberá llamar a la propiedad como una función para que la ejecute.

```
cuenta.total()
```

La otra alternativa es el uso de proxy:

```js
var cuenta = {
    haberes: 10000, 
    credito: 5000,
    total: undefined
}

var handler = {
  get : function(target, name){
      if(name === 'total'){
          return target.haberes - target.credito
      }
  }
}

var p = new Proxy(cuenta, handler);

console.log("Balance de la cuenta => ", p.total)
```

Si nos fijamos, a diferencia de la forma anterior, esta se ve algo más compleja, pero podemos llamar a nuestra propiedad tal como si fuera una propiedad, es decir, sin el uso de `()`.
Otra consideración importante es que luego hay que trabajar con el proxy y no con el objeto original, pero eso puede solucionarse si encapsulas el código en alguna estrategia de programación.